# Can I install latest Kubuntu (23.10) on top of dual boot with Windows with old Kubuntu version (13.10)?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, system-installation, kubuntu

I have a dual boot PC with old versions of Kubuntu and Windows installed.
I can't upgrade Windows but I can/want to upgrade Kubuntu.
The Kubuntu installed version:

```
Kubuntu version: 13.10
Qt Version: 4.8.4
KDE Libs 4.11.3
Kernel version 3.11.0-12-generic 
OS Type: 64 bit
```

Is it possible to just install the latest Kubuntu on top (i.e. insert the DVD iso and start the installation) without breaking the dual boot? Or should I try to upgrade incrementally via updates?

In case it matters, I don't care about losing any data from the installed Kubuntu. What I am interested in is that the dual boot with the current Windows system along with any files in the Windows installation are not affected by the process

Comment: I think both your proposed ways should work. The first way would delete the user data you might have, because I would propose to format partitions. Otherwise, many old Kubuntu files might remain on drive. The second option is even safer, but would take much more time.

Comment: @nobody: 
1) Are you referring to the user data in the Kubuntu installation? Or it can affect the Windows user data too? 
2) what would be the problem of many old kubuntu files remaining? I have 500GB hard disk so I don't really care if a couple e.g. 1-2 GB of HD is left with garbage from the old Kubuntu.

Comment: @nobody: how would I go about an incremental upgrade? Currently I get errors of unreachable repositories etc

Comment: I am reffering to the user data in the Kubuntu installation? Windows installation should remain untouched. The problem of remaining old kubuntu files is mainly space and possibly some program using wrong library left on the drive (not very likely). However, I have never tried to install a new Ubunutu over the old one. I am not sure how it works. I think it should, but usually I rather formatted the partition to make sure it is clean.

Comment: Incremental upgrade will not work out of the box, because old distributions are not available any more on original addresses. You have to change the links to the repositories. Here are one of available instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: You should know that incremental upgrades cannot be done in one step, because you are so far behind. You should upgrade form 13.10 to 14.04, to 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04 to 22.04. I am not sure if upgrade to old 16.04. This link https://askubuntu.com/questions/999360/how-can-i-upgrade-my-eol-16-10-to-any-new-version gives a hint it is not possible any more. Therefore, you might be left with a fresh installation option only.

Comment: Take a look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750586/is-there-a-path-to-upgrade-an-old-ubuntu-14-04-6-lts