# Boot Linux into RAM from ISO file on hard drive and do a clean Linux reinstallation

Tags: ubuntu, grub, hard-disk, iso

I have the following case:

A Ubuntu 14.04 installation should be upgraded to version 22.04. The hard drive needs to be repartitioned and the old 14.04 installation should be wiped completely. Ubuntu 14.04 uses LVM on the hard drive.

Is it possible to configure GRUB to load the .iso file for Ubuntu 22.04 into RAM and then boot the .iso file from RAM? I have been able to modify GRUB to start the .iso file from the hard drive (that has Ubuntu 22.04), but I can not repartition the hard drive, because it is in use (even if I have used "toram" option in GRUB entry for loading Linux).

If I boot the machine from an USB stick with Ubuntu 22.04, then it is possible repartition the hard drive. But I need some way to start the installation from the hard drive and do a clean installation without any USB sticks. I have some computers in remote locations, so I would need to be able to reinstall those without going on site.

Comment: See [the accepted answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829917/can-i-boot-a-live-usb-fully-to-ram-allowing-me-to-remove-the-disk) and [the tutorial](https://calvin.me/create-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-live-usb-even-boots-ram/) from a comment.  Note that if you boot the USB to RAM like you've described, you are allowed to `unmount` the HDD.  It's only the LiveCD/USB that GRUB booted to that must stay mounted.

Comment: There's also [this much safer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750586/is-there-a-path-to-upgrade-an-old-ubuntu-14-04-6-lts) but longer option.  Perform an upgrade between LTS releases, going from 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04 etc until you reach the desired release.  This method will also work better given that editing config files remotely is easier than trying to boot correctly

Comment: Check df and free. With toram, /cdrom should be /dev/shm, not any other device. If the ISO was loaded from a file (loop device) you might have to `losetup -D`, `umount` the filesystem that provided the ISO. If an existing swap partition was activated, you might have to `swapoff -a`. Ideally all of these should happen automatically, but isoloop/toram are exotic enough features that it might be a problem...

Comment: How is your hard drive partitioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/ubiquity/issues/51) and also tested that this works.

In short, the procedure was the following:

1. Extract an existing Ubuntu 22.04 ISO installation file to a temporary location.
2. Extract the `casper/initrd` file to a temporary location.
3. Add the following lines to the `casper/scripts/casper-bottom/05mountpoints` file (just before the last line in the file):

```
if grep -q '^[^ ]* /isodevice ' /proc/mounts; then
    mkdir -p /root/isodevice
    mount -n -o move /isodevice /root/isodevice.
fi
```

(I actually skipped the if statement, only added the mkdir and mount commands)

4. Repack the initrd file and replace the original one.
5. Repack the ISO file.
6. Copy the modified ISO file to the hard drive where grub can then find it.
7. Restart the computer and boot the ISO file using `toram` option in grub.
8. Open a terminal window and type the following commands:

```
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
sudo umount /isodevice
```

9. Now you should be able to repartition the hard drive and install Ubuntu 22.04 over Ubuntu 14.04 on the same hard drive (without having to go through all normal upgrading steps 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04 which doesn't work so well).

Without these steps Ubuntu 22.04 couldn't repartition hard drive (where it was booted from) and GParted complained that there were a file system in use.

Answer (score 0):

Grub doesn't do that. All Grub does is load kernel/initrd and pass parameters. Ubuntu then loads itself into ram. Grub is not further involved in that process.

`toram` is a feature implemented by Ubuntu's kernel/initrd. Other live images may be using a different name for a similar feature, or may not implement it at all.

In general this feature will require a sufficient amount of ram to be available to work. On memory constrained machines, it might fail altogether. The image has to fit in RAM entirely and then still have enough free RAM to actually do any installation work.

You can check if `toram` is in the kernel parameters from the command line:

```
$ grep toram /proc/cmdline
… toram …
```

The following output was produced with Ubuntu 22.04 desktop amd64.

Output of `df` with `toram` enabled (/dev/shm as /cdrom):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           972M  1.5M  971M   1% /run
/dev/shm        3.8G  3.6G  182M  96% /cdrom
/cow            4.8G   58M  4.7G   2% /
tmpfs           4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           972M  128K  972M   1% /run/user/999
```

Output of `df` with `toram` disabled (/dev/usbstick as /cdrom, nothing else mounted):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem    1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            995092    1496    993596   1% /run
/dev/usbstick   3737140 3737140         0 100% /cdrom
/cow            4975444   58760   4916684   2% /
tmpfs           4975444       0   4975444   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4975444       0   4975444   0% /tmp
tmpfs            995088     120    994968   1% /run/user/999
```

Output of `free` with `toram` enabled (3.6Gi shared, 4.9Gi available):

```
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.5Gi       736Mi       4.4Gi       3.6Gi       4.4Gi       4.9Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
```

Output of `free` with `toram` disabled (81Mi shared, 8.5Gi available):

```
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.5Gi       727Mi       4.4Gi        81Mi       4.4Gi       8.5Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
```

This will look different depending on the system but roughly that's how it's supposed to work. The ram requirements for server or netboot images may be different.